# Is it possible to check birthday?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I have a list that contains 2 columns. The first one is full name and the second one is birthday.
It is possible to do new calendar list and put there the birthdays from the other list?
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to just copy the 2nd column (birthday) to a new calendar list?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just adding the Look up column in the Calendar list, which will pull the Birthday column for the list and display in calendar.

here is detail who you can do this(they use the task list but you do it according to your need).
[http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_server/sharepoint-2010---working-with-lookup-columns-in-document-libraries-(part-1).aspx](http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_server/sharepoint-2010---working-with-lookup-columns-in-document-libraries-%28part-1%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you have to create a Calendar View for the First List having birthdays.

Then you can use the concept of 'Calendar Overlay' to achieve your requirement.

Details : http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/calendar-overlay-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-ootb-master-calendar/

Comment: I didn't understand how it helps me..

Comment: Lets say you have a List A where you added names & birthdays. If you want to show birthdays in another Calendar List B then you have to some way link it up with List A. You can do it simply by using Calendar Overlay or using Look-ups as mentioned by @waqas If you want to go a complex route you can use Event Receivers or Timer Jobs too to push data from one list to another.